# CSS: Background image stretch for all aspect ratios?

Tags: css, image, background

Refer to http://www.squarespace.com and their splash page background image. No matter what aspect ratio the window is resized to the image does not tile. I know the image dimensions must be large but the images I use are 6+ megapixels and mine still tile when the window is resized to tall and narrow to replicate an iPhone, for example.

What background image CSS settings is squarespace.com using for their splash images?

My current settings:

```
position:absolute;
top:0;
right:0;
bottom:0;
left:0;
background-position:center center;
background-size:100% auto;
background-image:url(../images/zzz.jpg);
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size is the `cover` what you are looking for? http://jsfiddle.net/95SQ2/

Comment: Absolutely is, thank you. That is brilliant. If you answer my question I will vote it as the best answer.

Comment: That's alright, there is an answer with the correct solution already

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `background-size: cover` will stretch the background image to fit both the width and height, regardless of aspect ratio.

Answer (score 1):

Change the settings as below

```
background-image: url('../images/zzz.jpg');
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
left: 0%;
top: 0%;
```

And if your page has scrolling content, then include the following too.

```
background-attachment: fixed;
background-size: 100% 100%;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

But still you have a chance of background image getting stretched. To avoid that you have to use javascript to choose the different size image according to the screen resolution as in http://www.squarespace.com.